# How to create an application layer for sockets python3

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, tcp

I have been looking at sockets in python and I have create a simple socket server and client. I am curious as to how to create an Application Layer (I believe thats what its called but I'm not completely sure) for my own socket server; examples would be like:

> http://
>
> ftp://
>
> mongodb://
>
> smb://
>
> etc..

So creating my own one of those for my socket server. I am unsure how to word this so I apologise.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/
You can use Tarnado Python library for Implementing websocket application layer